# Does Wordpress Super User or Administrators can create and edit post and media on behalf of a user

Tags: posts, users, uploads, media-library, management

For my project I need to administrate user post and media without access to it personal account.
So I must be able to create and edit a post (by is user name) before or after it has been created on behalf of a user.

On the head of custom post (custom plugin and specific wpdb table) I inserted a dropdown "select" based on `wp_dropdown_users();` to choose the author of media (that is also the user ID) that will be used to create or edit content of specific user.

Currently I can set the author ID (user ID) to the `wp.media` frame to display media from the selected author, but I can't find the parameter to specify which author to upload a new media. The 'author' parameter is located in `wp.media.options.library` object and it concerns only the `Media library` not the upload frame/tab.

Can `wp_set_current_user()` do the job ?
Can it be used to allow administrator to create or edit on behalf of specific user and overwrite wp.media parameters to open and upload media ?
Otherwise Is there a function/hook/filter that would allow this only for custom plugin page/post and super admin or administrator?

Somebody can explain me how works wp.media object and how it defined the user and author that owns media? Does it use the session cookie and/or the user Logged in cookie?

[Wordpress wp.media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media) is poorly documented and the [GitHub wp jsdocs](https://atimmer.github.io/wordpress-jsdoc/media_views_embed.js.html) is too difficult To be assimilated.

```
function generate_mediaframe(userId){
        $('#btnOpenMediaLibFrame').click(e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var  media_lib_frame = wp.media({
                multiple: false,
                library: {
                    type: 'image',
                    uploadedTo : wp.media.view.settings.post.id,
                    author: userId
                }
            });
            media_lib_frame.open();
            $(e.target).addClass('ActiveFrame');
        });
}
```

Comment: `wp_set_current_user` is not the solution you are looking for and has nothing to do with this. This has nothing to do with the role of the user, what's likely happened is you've added an `author` parameter expecting it to set the `author` on the off-chance that it existed and was supported, but it isn't and doesn't exist or has a different ID

Comment: confirmed, I can find no evidence that the code you posted supports or has ever supported an `author` field for this use case, and that if it did it would be for filtering what was shown in the media library. The `wp.media` call does not provide any ways to influence the attributes of uploaded media once the frame is open in that way. Additionally, `wp_set_current_user` is a PHP function not a JS function, and it's purpose is to set the current users session, not to specify the author of an attachment post

Comment: About `wp_set_current_user` I was expecting to add an exception in session cookie to authorize SuperAdmin or Administrator to create and edit on behalf of user. I understand this is not its function at all.

Comment: you'd still need to communicate the user to set to the AJAX handler, at which point why not set it when inserting the post and avoid using it? Doing that would still require sending the author ID with the AJAX request from the media library, which leads you straight back to square one

Answer (score 0):

> Somebody can explain me how works wp.media object and how it defined the user and author that owns media? Does it use the session cookie and/or the user Logged in cookie?

This is not something that can be done with the `wp.media` call, not attributes will allow this or can be used to set this. This approach is a dead end.

Instead of trying to brute force the media library code into doing what you want, instead it would be much easier to do this:

> When the media library has picked an image, ensure it has an author ID of X

Now the problem becomes a simple 2 step part which is much easier:

1. How do I retrieve the ID of the selected attachment form the media frame?
2. Given an attachment ID and a user ID, how do I set the user as the attachments author?

The first one is demonstrated in almost every tutorial of how to use `wp.media` to create an uploader and is the most common use case and best documented part of the code, and one you likely already have implemented.

The second has many options, ranging from creating your own AJAX handlers, using the REST API media endpoint to update the post author, to using `wp.media` itself!

In theory something like this *might* work:

```js
attachment = wp.media.attachment( imageId );
attachment.fetch();
if ( desiredUserID != attachment.attributes.author ) {
    attachment.attributes.author = desiredUserID;
    attachment.save();
}
```

Note that if the user is able to pick images that have already been uploaded this means they can take over other peoples posts. This also will require the user to be able to make an authenticated request and can edit other users attachments, which won't be an issue for an admin but might be elsewhere if you expand on this.

The important thing, is that you don't have to mess with the internals of `wp.media` to do it all in one step. It would be nice if you could, but that doesn't mean it's the only method available to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these explanations . Is [this](https://atimmer.github.io/wordpress-jsdoc/wp.media.model.Attachment.html) documentation page correspond to your  suggestion ?

Comment: unknown, what you've linked to is a description of the `Attachment` class that implements a backbone model, none of which I was aware of when I wrote my answer. If `wp.media.attachment` returns an object of that type then yes, but I do not have the answer to that, you will need to test and verify this yourself. Be mindful that by even asking that question you've put yourself in the top 0.01% of WP developers familiar with the Media libraries internals, very very few people understand the entire system and how it all fits together past a certain point

Comment: for reference, I arrived at the above answer by searching and this was the top result: https://dev.to/kelin1003/utilising-wordpress-media-library-for-uploading-files-2b01 I spotted `wp.media.attachment` in the code examples, opened up the browser console and executed it, then saw it had an `attributes` `fetch` and `save` method. If I were in your shoes the other option I would have taken was using the REST API directly in conjunction via `fetch`, especially if I only had to create and set the attachment, and had no need of a picker UI

Comment: I'm really a long way from being at this level since you're guiding me through my learning process. But this is the only reference I could find for customising wp.media frame. What do you think about `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()` ? ' I'm not sure about [it functionality](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js/). It talks about json encoding and I suppose it's for ajax/Rest use, am I wrong? I'm going to try out all your advice.

Comment: that's a PHP function, it wouldn't let you modify wp.media's post author. If you want a PHP based solution you would still need to communicate which user you want as the author and have that stored somewhere you can retrieve it from a PHP filter. At that point you could filter the creation of the attachment, but this is still completely backwards. `wp.media` is running in the browser in javascript, `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` is a PHP function on the server that takes an attachment and generates JSON output. It's possibly used in the response to the upload handler _after_ the upload occurs

Comment: Unless you can get the media library frames uploader to send the ID of the user you want in the AJAX request, then no PHP function will be of any use to you. If you did manage to change the author ID in `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js` for example it would only give the appearance as it isn't changing the attachment or the database, just the dressing up of it in JSON to generate output

Comment: I should stress that outside of a handful of PHP functions for enquing the media library frame and handling its AJAX, the media library frame is a backbone JS app that sits aside, most of the functions you're going to find have little to do with that specific JS app and more to do with generic general image management, and most people do not use it for more involved tasks, most people doing involved work with those APIs are trying to extend the media library to add new tabs or sections, filters, DAMs etc.

Comment: With regards to the actual PHP side of things, if you can put an `author` field inside `post_data` then the HTTP request made to `async-upload.php` will happily process it and it'll make its way to `wp_insert_post` just fine with no PHP code changes needed. Your problem is entirely JS based

Comment: Further investigation suggested that `wp.Uploader` may be a viable route, and that changing its defaults to include an `author` parameter may be the answer. This did not work and the `author` parameter was not sent. I don't believe the media library is what's actually uploading the file, WPUpload is doing that via the pupload library. I can find nowhere to insert the `author` parameter. My recommendation of modifying the attachment after the media library has selected it is still the best case scenario

Comment: Thanks a lot for your research , I appreciate. Returning to your answer,  the `"imageId"` is impossible to get before image was upload. Does your suggestion is useful to update author image on wp.media.on.close() function ? Otherwise,does it exist a function that trigger during the upload or at the end on upload media action ?

Comment: It was my understanding you would set the author when you know the image ID, the media library provides no events I’ve been able to find, most likely because it doesn’t perform the upload itself. If I knew of such an event I would have written a very different answer but even the. You can’t know the image ID before the upload happens as there is no image ID unless you found a secret to time travel. You will need to set the author afterwards. Though at this point you’ve gone to an awful lot of effort to try and get this working when a file input and a form processor would have done just fine

Comment: Hi. I'm going to use an easiest method considering your advice and suggestions (but it will perform less well). However I stand by my initial reasoning : When I create a new Post on behalf of a user, I define the user of post from the outset and fill all informations.That's allow me to display only media from choosen User). Now I'm working to add the image ID to the choosen author when I submit the Post with `wp_update_post`.

Comment: if you can set the author of the parent post the attachment is attached to, then this entire problem can be sidestepped with a filter that sets the attachment posts author to that of its parent post. Note that the entire concept of doing something on behalf of a user is not a WordPress thing, it's your process that sits on top. On a technical level there is no such thing as "on behalf", and `wp_insert_post` does not care about that